# Count in savedSearch kibana

Tags: kibana

I'm using kibana safesearch to get an extract of data in csv and as I'm quite new to this I came here to get some help .I need to count how many times we got the occurences of product  in the json file I use(or i've got a field name "ref" with a values associated but it from 0 to 99 and I need it to be 1 to 1000). Here an example of files I use :

```
    {
  "header": {
    "salesOrderId": "toto",
    "salesOrderDate" : "2021-02-16T19:04:14+01:00",
    "salesOrderChangeVersion": "0",
    "purchaseOrderRequestId": "uncle",
    "requestNumber": "00005",
    "channel":"TEST",
    "requestStatus": "ORDER_COMPLETE"
  },
  "reject": [],
  "offer": [
    {
      "offerCode": "3150",
      "offerFunctionalVersion": "1.0",
      "contract":{
        "contractNumber":"1-10000361221",
        "contractVersionNumber":"0"
      },
      "criterion": [
        {
          "criterionCode": "firstStampPosition",
          "criterionValue": "1"
        },
        {
          "criterionCode": "maxWeight",
          "criterionValue": "20"
        },
        {
          "criterionCode": "specimenFlag",
          "criterionValue": "0"
        }
      ],
      "customer": {
        "custAccNumber": "777",
        "customerType": "PAR"
      },
      "product": [
        {
          "productCode": "4L",
          "criterion": [
            {
              "criterionCode": "sheet_formatCode",
              "criterionValue": "L12A"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "ref",
              "criterionValue": "0"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "marking_template",
              "criterionValue": "stp1_fr"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "logo",
              "criterionValue": "link here"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "weight",
              "criterionValue": "21"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "stamp_mention",
              "criterionValue": "Utilisable par multiple au-delà de 20g"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "signedFlag",
              "criterionValue": "1"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "marking_productLabel",
              "criterionValue": "Lettre verte"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "SD_originCode",
              "criterionValue": "87"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "soCode",
              "criterionValue": "381"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "asCode",
              "criterionValue": "A10"
            },
            {
              "criterionCode": "countryCode",
              "criterionValue": "250"
            }
          ],
          "criteriaGroup": [
            {
              "criteriaGroupCode": "addressGroup",
              "criteriaGroupIndex": "0",
              "criterion": [
                {
                  "criterionCode": "receiver_address_name1",
                  "criterionValue": "M et Mme DUTEST"
                },
                {
                  "criterionCode": "receiver_address_add4",
                  "criterionValue": "33 rue de la force"
                },
                {
                  "criterionCode": "receiver_address_zipCode",
                  "criterionValue": "3417012"
                },
                {
                  "criterionCode": "receiver_address_town",
                  "criterionValue": "Far far away"
                },
                {
                  "criterionCode": "receiver_address_countryCode",
                  "criterionValue": "260"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "criteriaGroupCode" : "sheet_Group",
              "criteriaGroupIndex" : "0",
              "criterion" : [
                {
                  "criterionCode": "sheet_formatCode",
                  "criterionValue": "L12A"
                },
                {
                  "criterionCode": "sheet_SDFlag",
                  "criterionValue": "1"
                },
                {
                  "criterionCode": "sheet_contractFlag",
                  "criterionValue": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "service": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answer I've found was :

```
try { 
     return doc['offer.product.productCode'].size(); 
} catch(Exception e){ 
   return ''; 
}
```